# PXE boot via EFI - DHCP completes, but TFTP never kicks off or tries to transfer file

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, uefi, tftp

I am attempting to PXE boot a VM via EFI and have tried both via Foreman and Cobbler. The server used for DHCP/TFTP is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and the server I'm trying to kickstart is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I've also tried Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

My DHCP config file reads as:

```
default-lease-time 43200;
max-lease-time 86400;

not authoritative;
ddns-update-style none;

option domain-name "spectric.dev";
option domain-name-servers dns.spectric.dev,10.48.30.50,10.48.30.253;
option ntp-servers none;

allow booting;
allow bootp;

option fqdn.no-client-update    on;  # set the "O" and "S" flag bits
option fqdn.rcode2            255;
option pxegrub code 150 = text ;

# required for UEFI HTTP boot
if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 10) = "HTTPClient" {
  option vendor-class-identifier "HTTPClient";
}

# promote vendor in dhcpd.leases
set vendor-string = option vendor-class-identifier;

# next server and filename options
next-server 10.48.30.102;
option architecture code 93 = unsigned integer 16 ;
if option architecture = 00:06 {
  filename "grub2/grubia32.efi";
} elsif option architecture = 00:07 {
  filename "grub2/grubx64.efi";
} elsif option architecture = 00:09 {
  filename "grub2/grubx64.efi";
} else {
  filename "pxelinux.0";
}

log-facility local7;

include "/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.hosts";
# spectric.dev
subnet 10.48.30.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  pool
  {
    range 10.48.30.50 10.48.30.100;
  }

  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 10.48.30.255;
  option domain-search "spectric.dev";
}
```

Output of my `tcpdump` for DHCP traffic during the PXE attempt:

```
root:~# tcpdump -i ens160 port 67 or port 68 -e -n -vv
tcpdump: listening on ens160, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:58:42.312622 00:0c:29:43:12:d5 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 389: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 50402, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 375)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:0c:29:43:12:d5, length 347, xid 0x4a79134f, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:0c:29:43:12:d5
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1472
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 35:
              Subnet-Mask, Time-Zone, Default-Gateway, Time-Server
              IEN-Name-Server, Domain-Name-Server, Hostname, BS
              Domain-Name, RP, EP, RSZ
              TTL, BR, YD, YS
              NTP, Vendor-Option, Requested-IP, Lease-Time
              Server-ID, RN, RB, Vendor-Class
              TFTP, BF, GUID, Option 128
              Option 129, Option 130, Option 131, Option 132
              Option 133, Option 134, Option 135
            GUID Option 97, length 17: 0.86.77.151.201.146.26.10.66.6.241.183.233.172.67.18.213
            NDI Option 94, length 3: 1.3.0
            ARCH Option 93, length 2: 7
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 32: "PXEClient:Arch:00007:UNDI:003000"
22:58:42.312951 00:0c:29:e5:da:db > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    10.48.30.50.67 > 255.255.255.255.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x4a79134f, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Your-IP 10.48.30.89
          Server-IP 10.48.30.50
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:0c:29:43:12:d5
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Offer
            Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 10.48.30.50
            Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 2053495
            Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.255.0
            Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 10.48.30.50
            Domain-Name Option 15, length 12: "spectric.dev"
            BR Option 28, length 4: 10.48.30.255
22:58:42.315032 00:0c:29:0c:f1:f9 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    10.48.30.102.67 > 255.255.255.255.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x4a79134f, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Your-IP 10.48.30.89
          Server-IP 10.48.30.102
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:0c:29:43:12:d5
          file "grub2/grubx64.efi"
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Offer
            Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 10.48.30.102
            Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 43200
            Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.255.0
            Default-Gateway Option 3, length 4: 10.48.30.255
            Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 10.48.30.50
            Domain-Name Option 15, length 12: "spectric.dev"
22:58:43.361465 00:09:0f:09:01:12 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 377: (tos 0x10, ttl 16, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 363)
    10.48.30.1.67 > 255.255.255.255.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 335, xid 0x4a79134f, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Your-IP 10.48.30.104
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:0c:29:43:12:d5
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Offer
            Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 10.48.30.1
            Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 604800
            Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.255.0
            Default-Gateway Option 3, length 4: 10.48.30.1
            Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 12: 10.48.30.50,1.1.1.3,1.0.0.3
            NTP Option 42, length 4: 10.48.30.1
            RN Option 58, length 4: 302400
            RB Option 59, length 4: 529200
            T224 Option 224, length 33: 70.71.49.48.48.70.84.75.50.49.48.48.52.54.56.49.70.71.49.48.48.70.84.75.50.49.48.48.52.57.49.52.0
22:58:46.129783 00:0c:29:43:12:d5 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 401: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 50403, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 387)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:0c:29:43:12:d5, length 359, xid 0x4a79134f, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:0c:29:43:12:d5
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Request
            Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 10.48.30.102
            Requested-IP Option 50, length 4: 10.48.30.89
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 65280
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 35:
              Subnet-Mask, Time-Zone, Default-Gateway, Time-Server
              IEN-Name-Server, Domain-Name-Server, Hostname, BS
              Domain-Name, RP, EP, RSZ
              TTL, BR, YD, YS
              NTP, Vendor-Option, Requested-IP, Lease-Time
              Server-ID, RN, RB, Vendor-Class
              TFTP, BF, GUID, Option 128
              Option 129, Option 130, Option 131, Option 132
              Option 133, Option 134, Option 135
            GUID Option 97, length 17: 0.86.77.151.201.146.26.10.66.6.241.183.233.172.67.18.213
            NDI Option 94, length 3: 1.3.0
            ARCH Option 93, length 2: 7
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 32: "PXEClient:Arch:00007:UNDI:003000"
22:58:46.130130 00:0c:29:e5:da:db > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    10.48.30.50.67 > 255.255.255.255.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x4a79134f, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Your-IP 10.48.30.89
          Server-IP 10.48.30.50
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:0c:29:43:12:d5
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: ACK
            Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 10.48.30.50
            Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 2053491
            Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.255.0
            Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 10.48.30.50
            Domain-Name Option 15, length 12: "spectric.dev"
            BR Option 28, length 4: 10.48.30.255
22:58:46.130264 00:0c:29:0c:f1:f9 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    10.48.30.102.67 > 255.255.255.255.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x4a79134f, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Your-IP 10.48.30.89
          Server-IP 10.48.30.102
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:0c:29:43:12:d5
          file "grub2/grubx64.efi"
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: ACK
            Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 10.48.30.102
            Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 43200
            Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.255.0
            Default-Gateway Option 3, length 4: 10.48.30.255
            Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 10.48.30.50
            Domain-Name Option 15, length 12: "spectric.dev"
```

Logs only show DHCP offer/request/ack, then nothing after. I tested connecting via TFTP from another server to the server hosting the PXE files and successfully transferred the file (verified the traffic with tcpdump on TFTP ports, too).

Am I missing something evident in the DHCP config which isn't allowing the transfer to kick off? Or is something glaringly evident to any of you?

As input above, I have tested and verified TFTP traffic works successfully. I have also tried running TFTP via xinet and tftpd-hpa, with the configuration currently still running via tftpd-hpa. DHCP is via isc-dhcp-server and seems to offer the lease just fine, and communicates what file is needed. In other environments I've been in, I typically see the `tftpd` service (regardless of its source) request the file, transfer, and begin the boot process during the PXE EFI boot, but this system isn't moving into TFTPing anything after DHCP completes.